# ChromeVox does not correctly read the aria-expanded attribute for a button wrapping an image

Tags: google-chrome, wai-aria, screen-readers

When using a `<button>` or `<a>` tag which wraps another element, e.g. an `<img>`, the Chrome Screen Reader (ChromeVox) does not correctly read the current `aria-expanded` attribute value of the button *if the user clicks on it with a mouse*. (This is despite the javascript events firing and updating the attribute value correctly.) However using the cursors to navigate and click the button will correctly read the aria-expanded value.

E.g., for some html like this:

```html
<button id="btn" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="details">
  <svg height="100" width="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red"></circle>
  </svg>
</button>
```

and some supporting javascript:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  expanded = this.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true';           
  if (expanded) {
    this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
  } else {
    this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
  }
});
```

The screen reader will not read the current value of `aria-expanded`.

I've created a simple jsFiddle to demonstrate the problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/martynw/ebpyzkm4/4/

My guess is that the screenreader events are tied to the inner elements (image etc) of the button and do not bubble up to the button itself?

This problem seems particular to ChromeVox (tested in version 53.0.2784.14); it does seem to behave correctly in Safari + Apple VoiceOver.

Comment: The button is currently lacking any accessible name. Is the issue reproducible with a name? In any case, ChromeVox gained popularity among web developers who want to test, but [not among real users (0.9%)](https://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey9/#primary)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s simply a bug report. These is no question here.